# Amount of PEG to add to copper plating solution?

Tags: electroplating

I found [a paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/8/11/2135) about making a copper plating solution and thought I'd give it a shot. Please keep in mind I have no formal education in chemistry. I have a few questions about the preparation of the solution.

#### Information:

The paper lists the following ingredients:

[image: Ingredients]

In the conclusion, the authors recommend the following additives:

- 500 ppm PEG
- 5 ppm SPS
- 30 ppm JGB

#### PEG:

The PEG I have is labeled as PEG 400. The paper doesn't say anything about this. I assume the paper calculates as if it was pure PEG, where mine is 400 g / mol? Could someone guide me on how to calculate the quantity needed to achieve 500 ppm?

#### Cl-:

For chlorine, I am considering hydrochloric acid. The concentration of the acid I have is 30%, and I would need 1.4 mM of chlorine. Since I need only a very small amount, It might be best to dilute the concentrated acid. I do have a very precise scale, but weighing out 0.05 gram seems a bit ridiculous.

#### Results:

Here is what I've calculated so far:

| Chemical | Molar mass | Required | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CuSO4 5H2O | 159.609 g/mol | 0.79 M | 126 grams |
| H2SO4 | 98.079 g/mol | 1.02 M | 100 grams |
| HCl | 36.46 g/mol | 1.40 mM | 0.05 grams |
| SPS | - | 5 ppm | 5 milligrams |
| JGB | - | 30 ppm | 30 milligrams |
| PEG400 | - | 500 ppm | (Not sure) |

This is for a 1-liter solution, with the remainder being deionized water. I'm aware of the acid-to-water addition protocol.

#### Prepare scaled down solutions:

Make 1% SPS solution:
1000 mg SPS + 9000 mg water = 10000mg of 1% solution.

Make 1% JGB solution:
1000 mg JGB + 9000 mg water = 10000mg of 1% solution.

Make 1% PEG solution:
1000 mg PEG + 9000 mg water = 10000mg of 1% solution.

Make 1% HCl solution:
100 mg HCl @ 36% + 3500 mg water = 3600 mg of 1% solution.
1% HCl => 36.46 / 0.01 = 3646 g/mol

#### Prepare electrolyte 1 kilo (more or less 1 liter)

Add CuSO4 5H2O:
CuSO4 5H2O = 159.609 g/mol
0.79M * 159.609 g/mol = 126 gram

Add H2SO4:
H2SO4 = 98.079 g/mol (Mine is 98%)
1.02M * 98.079 g/mol = 100 gram

Add HCl:
HCl @ 1% = 3646 g/mol
0.0014M * 3646 g/mol = 5.1044 gram

Add PEG:
500ppm of PEG = 500 mg total
500mg @ 1% = 50 gram

Add SPS:
5ppm of SPS = 5 mg total
5mg @ 1% = 0.5 gram

Add JGB:
30ppm of JGB = 30 mg total
30mg @ 1% = 3 gram

#### Power supply:

The paper specifies a particular waveform. For now I would like to ignore this and just use a current limited DC power supply.

#### References:

Shin S-H, Kim T-Y, Park J-H, Suh S-J. Optimization of Additive and Current Conditions for Void-Free Filled Through-Silicon Via. Applied Sciences. 2018; 8(11):2135. https://doi.org/10.3390/app8112135

Comment: Not sure about the significance of the choice of PEG MW, but for calculating ppm that would be irrelevant. Also, you have a lot of latitude in the choice of amount of PEG to add: $$\pu{100-500 ppm }= \pu{100-500 x 10^-6 g~PEG/g} ~\textrm{solution} \\ \approx \pu{100-500 x 10^-3 g~ PEG/kg~\textrm{solution}}$$  If you choose to make 1 kg (approx 1 L) of solution at a concentration of 500 ppm PEG that means adding 500 mg of PEG. Given the wide suggested range you probably don't need to be particularly accurate.

Comment: The choice of waveform is probably important, but this is not my specialty.

Comment: @BuckThorn, So then, what's the difference between PEG and PEG400? I know you also have PEG 3000 for example. From what I've read, it's the molar mass of the peg. But I doubt my bottle contains pure PEG, since it's a liquid.

Comment: You can read more about PEG on the Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene_glycol It's a polymer, and the number of monomers in a chain determines whether its a solid or liquid at room temperature. The low MW stuff is liquid

Comment: I have found some, not so reliable, claims on the internet that the PEG should be between 1500 and 3500. Since it's not too expensive, I ordered some PEG 1500.

Comment: In the description of the polymer, 400 is the probable molecular mass of the polymer PEG. As the monomer has a molecular mass equal to $62$, it means that the polymer is a mixture of hexamers and heptameters, which may be liquid.

Comment: Some practical remarks. 1) $\ce{HCl 1}$% does not have a molecular weight $3646$ as given in the text. Solutions like $\ce{HCl}$ $1$% do not have a molecular weight. Only pure substance have a molecular weight. $\ce{HCl}$ has a molecular weight of 36.46 g/mol.

Comment: Some practical remarks. 1) $\ce{HCl 1}$% does not have a molecular weight $3646$ as given in the text. Solutions like $\ce{HCl}$ $1$% do not have a molecular weight. Only pure substance have a molecular weight. Pure $\ce{HCl}$ has a molecular weight of 36.46 g/mol. 2) See under ...

Comment: 2) In the text, the $\ce{Cl-}$ concentration is obtained by adding $\ce{HCl}$. This is not a good idea, as first $\ce{HCl}$ is a gas. Gases are difficult to weigh, and to dissolve. And if you use commercial $\ce{HCl}$ solutions instead of the gas, it is not easy to weigh with precision small amounts of liquids, like less than one gram. You should rather replace $\ce{HCl}$ by $\ce{NaCl}$ which is easy to weigh with precision, whatever the quantity chosen.

Comment: If you want to make a solution of PEG $200$ ppm, it is not important to know which sort of PEG you use. $1$ liter PEG $200$ ppm, means $200$ mg or $0.2$ g PEG, whatever the choice of PEG. You may choose PEG $300$, or PEG $1500$, or any other sort off PEG. The only important thing is the necessity of adding $0.2$ g of this PEG in one liter water.

Comment: The same problem happens for $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{H2SO4}$. You may be sure of weighing $100$ g $\ce{H2SO4}$. But how will you be sure that this viscous liquid sample will be correctly transferred into water solution ? It is possible, but not easy. Think in advance about how to handle this corrosive liquid !